# ASP.NET gif not loading when deployed to heroku

Tags: html, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET web app which is not loading a gif image. Below is a snippet of the code that is not working. The `header.gif` loads fine while the `baby.gif` does not. Any suggestion on how I could fix this?

```
<div class="text-center">
    <h1><img src="/imagesGifs/Header.gif" /></h1>

    <!--columns-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <img src="/imagesGifs/baby.gif" width="100" height="200"/>
        </div>
```

I have tried using a imgur URL, relative path and even removing the width/height to match the working line and nothing seems to get the gif to load. I did as well confirm the spelling and letter case to ensure it matched the exact file. However when I test it locally it does work just fine until I deploy it to heroku.

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, what is the full URL of the request for this image?  What is the server's response?

Comment: Looks like its showing this message:
GET https://king-summer-web.herokuapp.com/imagesGifs/baby.gif 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Then it's not found on the server.  The code shown has no control over that.  You'll need to examine the server and the deployment of that file to the server and indicate why specifically you think it *should* be found there.

Comment: That makes sense and gives me a good start point vs what I was trying. Thank you David!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I forget again. Wanted to make a comment incase anyone has an issue similar to this. Turns out it was just an issue with the file, I ended up removing it and adding a new version of the gif and now it works just fine. So, in the end it seems to have been an issue with the file itself